# What is the maximum file size that will be cached by a browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer, browser-cache

Note that I *don't* mean the maximum size of the browser cache. I mean, what is the maximum size, if any, of individual files that will be cached by the major desktop browsers? Mobile versions optional.

Firefox appears to have a setting for this (`browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size`) but I can't find any information regarding this for other browsers like Chrome or IE/Edge, nor can I find a source that says Chrome and IE do not have file size limits.

This question was [originally asked on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/338722/82866), but only received an answer for Firefox before it was closed as off topic. The [solution in its comments](http://stevesouders.com/tests/cachesize/) does not work anymore. It stops at 4096KB, and will work if 8192KB is entered manually, but reverts to 512KB when 16384KB is tested.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not here to provide links to documentation (asking that is actually specifically off-topic), and requesting info about "the latest versions of..." will date this question quickly, which is bad. ;)  The solution was for finding out for yourself on SF in the comments (http://stevesouders.com/tests/cachesize/), so I'm not sure what else you need?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 1) I'm only asking for documentation if there is a limit and the documentation exists. So far, I have not been able to find any documentation. If it helps, I can remove the request for documentation. 2) The solution in the comments does not work anymore. It stops at 4096KB, and will work if 8192KB is entered manually, but reverts to 512KB when 16384KB is entered.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I just read the information on what I can and can't ask at http://superuser.com/help/asking and it doesn't say that asking for links to documentation is off topic. Search for "documentation" doesn't pull up anything at all. It also appears that the original question was marked as off topic because it was out of the scope of Server Fault, not because he requested documentation.

Comment: It counts as a "learning material recommendation".  From http://superuser.com/help/on-topic: "and it is not about … •asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation".  "The solution in the comments does not work anymore" you should state that in your question, along with your results from attempting it (that's the "showing your research" part)".  Anyhow, it takes more than just my vote to close it, I'm just sharing the rules as they currently stand (to my understanding).

Comment: I voted to close to. Shame as the question is well worded and interesting, sadly just off topic here!

Comment: I retracted my close vote, because the user edited into a usable form, that makes it not just requesting links to documentation. :)